# Login authorization, how to check if the password matches a SALT + HASH - PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hash, authentication, salt

I am currently working on a school project and I have recently made no progress towards completing the login authorization. I am using a HASH and a SALT to register the new users. I can not find any resources that make seance to me so I decided to make an account here to ask my very own question.

This is my register script :

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $first = $_POST['fname'];
    $last = $_POST['lname'];
    $salt = crypt("sha512", false);
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash("sha512", $salt . $pass . $salt, false);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `fname`, `lname`, `salt`, `password`) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$first', '$last', '$salt', '$password')";
```

Then I have a checklogin.php script that is the action="checklogin.php" on my index page which is the login page. This is the full script : http://pastebin.com/tKrsHaFU (paste bin)

My question is how do I validate my users that come to index.php page (login form) with the the users that are already in the database keep in mind I have a salt and Hash on the passwords.

Comment: Do a search for bcrypt instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all:

```
$salt = crypt("sha512", false);
```

That generates a static salt, i.e. no variation. To generate a better one:

```
$salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true); // the paranoid use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()
```

To validate the record, your SQL becomes:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// ...
if ($count==1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (hash('sha512', $row['salt'] . $_POST['mypassword'] . $row['salt']) == $row['password']) {
        // validation passed, rejoice!
    }
}
```

However, you should look here: [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need not worry so much !!

Now the basic idea behind any login script and also behind a database storing user info is that, we need minimum 1 value to be a primary key, which will uniquely identify each user.
Now in your case, its apt the `username` seems to be the primary key.

So all you need to do is simply execute a `$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name") or die(mysql_error());`

Here `table_name` will be the name of the table that stores all the user info. 
Now a `$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );` will put all the user info into an array.

A simple `var_dump($info)` will list you all the usernames along with other details of the users (Simply for testing purpose... u donot want to display dis info to users when they register :P )

Just loop through this array and match the username supplied by the new_user with that already existing in the array. If matches then you can stop him by saying `User already exists !!`. Else welcome him to your website.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you can read this article.  It shows the general design pattern.
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_2391-PHP-login-logout-and-easy-access-control.html

If you can get that much working, the next step will be to obscure the passwords in your data base.  You can use php *md5()* to make a one-way encoding of the password.  Apply *md5()* to the password when the client registers and store the encoded password.  Apply *md5()* to the clear-text password that the client enters into the login form.  Use the encoded password in your SELECT query.  You can concatenate a salt string into the md5() function call.  Just be sure to use the same salt every time.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Best regards, ~Ray

Comment: Well it is time to change for another hash function, MD5 is the bad! Check bcrypt as Jack said.

Comment: I hear this foolishness about md5 all the time.  It is simple, easy to use and very difficult to break.  If anyone wants to try breaking it, I will buy you a beer.  Just tell me the password that matches this string: e0f1299ed629d3c8826e2dd2be4780cf

Comment: @Ray Paseur - So we meet again, just tell me the password for this MD5 hash: 736417aff94df6884ea929e7014816a2 , if you think it is secure, then ask [Google](http://www.google.ch/#q=736417aff94df6884ea929e7014816a2)...

Comment: @martinstoeckli: Google (and any other rainbow attack site) can come up with a great many matches between a password and its md5() string.  There are even md5() sites just waiting for people to put in words, so they can build their vocabulary of md5() strings in the hope that a web site will get hacked so they can get the md5() strings, reverse-lookup the passwords and attack.  I understand this, and that is partly why a Salt is a good idea.  I also know that I can compute the md5() string quickly, but I may not be able to reverse it quickly.  Still waiting on that one, above ;-)

Comment: @RayPaseur - You are missing the point, it does **not** make the situation better, that you have an MD5 hash of a password, that cannot be easily brute-forced. Users will choose other and probably weaker passwords (a salt won't help here). So your offer to buy a beer is honorable, but it is no argument. Because a blowfish is an animal, not every animal is a blowfish.